# Using shorthand character classes inside character classes in R regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have defined

```
vec <- "5f 110y, Fast"
```

and

```
gsub("[\\s0-9a-z]+,", "", vec)
```

gives "`5f  Fast`"

I would have expected it to give "`Fast`" since everything before the comma should get matched by the regex.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not the case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should keep in mind that, in TRE regex patterns, you cannot use regex escapes like `\s`, `\d`, `\w` inside bracket expressions.

So, the regex in your case, `"[\\s0-9a-z]+,"`, matches 1 or more `\`, `s`, digits and lowercase ASCII letters, and then a single `,`.

You may use POSIX character classes instead, like `[:space:]` (any whitespaces) or `[:blank:]` (horizontal whitespaces):

```
> gsub("[[:space:]0-9a-z]+,", "", vec)
[1] " Fast"
```

Or, use a PCRE regex with `\s` and `perl=TRUE` argument:

```
> gsub("[\\s0-9a-z]+,", "", vec, perl=TRUE)
[1] " Fast"
```

To make `\s` match all Unicode whitespaces, add `(*UCP)` PCRE verb at the pattern start: `gsub("(*UCP)[\\s0-9a-z]+,", "", vec, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I wasn't aware of the distinction between TRE regex and other regex types.

Comment: @ThanksABundle Yeah, and your `"[\\s0-9a-z]+,"` TRE regex matches 1 or more ``\``, `s`, digits and lowercase ASCII letters, and then a single `,`. That is why it does not match as expected.

Comment: Can you explain why the '\\' works outside '[ ]' but not inside. Is this just a feature of TRE regex?

Comment: @ThanksABundle Inside bracket expressions, ``\`` is treated as a literal backslash. Outside of bracket expressions, ``\`` can be used to define regex escapes like `\s` (to match whitespaces), `\d` (digits), or to escape special chars like `(`, `[`, `*`, etc. You cannot escape them inside bracket expressions. To use `[`, `]`, `^` and ``\`` in a bracket expression in a TRE regex you can use `[]\[^-]` (`"[]\\[^-]"`).

Comment: To match a literal `\ `, outside of `[]` , you would have to escape it again: `\\\\ `.

Comment: @JAD Yes, to match a literal backslash in an input string, the pattern should contain two consecutive literal backslashes, and that means four consecutive ``\`` symbols in a string literal, `"\\\\"` (<- ``\\`` string).

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try folllowing and let me know if this helps you.

```
vec <- c("5f 110y, Fast")
gsub(".*,","",vec)
```

OR

```
gsub("[[:alnum:]]+ [[:alnum:]]+,","",vec)
```

Comment: Yes, this does indeed work here but is too general an expression for my needs in other cases. Anyway, I'm really only interested in why my above regex isn't working

Comment: @ThanksABundle, please check my OR solution now and let me know then?

Comment: Yes, thank you for this alternative solution. All the same, I'm still asking why my initial regex wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution would be to use `str_replace` with you original regex:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(vec, "[\\s0-9a-z]+,", "")
```

Comment: Yep, thanks! Was strange to me to find a difference in regex behaviour between gsub and str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Try a different regex:

```
gsub("[[:blank:][:digit:][:lower:]]+,", "", vec)
#[1] " Fast"
```

Or, to remove the space after the comma,

```
gsub("[[:blank:][:digit:][:lower:]]+, ", "", vec)
#[1] "Fast"
```